# How can I remove the blank line between elements?

Tags: php, html, css

How can I remove the blank line between the title and the table? Thanks!

```
  <?php
      echo "<h3>Presentaciones</h3>";
      echo "<table border='1'>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>row 1, field1</td>";
      echo "<td>row 1, field2</td>";
      echo "<td>row 1, field3</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>row 2, field1</td>";
      echo "<td>row 2, field2</td>";
      echo "<td>row 2, field3</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Change the css of the `h3` (I think you are getting the default padding/margin)..

Comment: Or change the css for the `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom: 0` in `h3`. 
Browsers has default styling and you must add your own rules in order to override them.

Below is the PHP output as HTML:

```css
h3{
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentaciones</h3><table border="1"><tbody><tr><td>row 1, field1</td><td>row 1, field2</td><td>row 1, field3</td></tr><tr><td>row 2, field1</td><td>row 2, field2</td><td>row 2, field3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your css file:

```css
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Presentaciones</h3>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <td>row 1, field1</td>
    <td>row 1, field2</td>
    <td>row 1, field3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, field1</td>
    <td>row 2, field2</td>
    <td>row 2, field3</td>
</table>
```